# Best approach for building text based data entry app

Tags: bash, ncurses, python-curses, urwid

I'm trying to write a script that just uses the terminal, but I don't know how realistic my expectations are. It's a data entry thing I want to make to make my life easier. I would like something that looks like this:

```
100456 John Doe      []  ()  ()  ()  ()  [                        ]
100873 Alice Everly  []  ()  ()  ()  ()  [                        ]
...
...
```

Basically a screen with a list of 20-30 people with text entry boxes and check boxes. I want to be able to arrow up and down and move around. I remember using text based programs way back when and they still just seem more efficient.

I've been looking at ncurses, urwid, straight bash... I think I can get any of these to work, but if anyone has a suggestion on a language or framework that would make this easier, I'd sure appreciate it. I don't want to get a week or two in and then realize I could have done it another way in an hour.

Comment: Node.js and javascript can save you some time

Comment: I always thought javascript and node.js was specifically html focused. I'll take a look to see if it does what I want. I actually see a text based adventure game that says it was written using node.js, so I guess I was wrong! Thanks.

Comment: A possibility is tcl/tk

Comment: The old text based apps on UNIX were probably built in C using the ncurses library. It wasn't difficult. These libraries still exist so if you fancy some C coding then go for it. To do this in pure bash, well being an old UNIX hack I am tempted to suggest looking at fmli (or whatever equivalent there is in bash these days).